# cakePHP: Can you query the database from a helper class?

Tags: cakephp-1.3, helper

Hi just need to know whether you can query the database from inside a helper class, whether you should and how you do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, by passing a reference to the Model into the View as a variable via $this->set() and then querying it...but you shouldn't. It's messy ;-)

CakePHP uses the MVC model, and helpers are part of the View (the V of MVC) - their job is purely to display the (already available) information passed to it from the controller.

If your view needs extra information , then your controller should have already queried the Models to get it.

I'd suggest you read up on the MVC model if you're not familiar with it, then some refactoring might be in order!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked as correct - it doesn't answer the question at all - I'd also like to know how to put common database requests into helper files in cakephp.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can query the database from your helper file. Please check this :-

```
class YourHelperNameHelper extends AppHelper {

    function queryDbFromHelper()
    {
        // Load your model here
        App::import('Model','ModelName');
        $this->ModelName = new ModelName();

        //now you can use find method or another method to query DB.
        return $this->ModelName->find('all'); 
    }
}
// Include this helper in controller
var $helpers = array('YourHelperName');

// call this function in helper file.
$this->YourHelperName->queryDbFromHelper();
```

Comment: This solution works and it answers the original question. And it's hardly messy at all. We're not here for a Sermon on the Tenets of MVC. We have problems to solve as quickly as possible, with as little breakage to existing code as possible.